# Restrict WEBAPI OData fields returned from controller

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth, odata

I have created a working C#.NET WEBAPI using OData v4 for returning data from my Entity Framework entities. However, what I need to do is selectively restrict the columns that are returned per entity for the current authenticated request (*User*). Therefore, if no $select is included in the request, I do not want to return all columns. I require the controller to do the selecting (or restricting) of columns returned. I.e. From my Customer Entity, *User A* might have access to the Telephone column whereas *User B* might not.

I can successfully filter the $filter by creating a new attribute and therefore feel I should be able to do a similar thing for the default columns returned. However, I have not been able to find anything.

So here I am asking for help.

Thank you in advance.

Ian